# Choose a Spinner from a specific theme

Tags: android, spinner, android-theme

How can I get the `Holo Spinner` in a Light Activity, or the opposite?

Because if I put HoloTheme for the Activity, every `View` will be Holo...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `style` attribute in your XML to define a style for individual Views.

In this case, you are looking for:

```
<Spinner
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Spinner" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a theme with all characteristics of Light except for its spinner which is set as the spinner that Holo uses, and use that theme.